# How to find out new pages / lists / listitems added to the intranet site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to find what new pages / lists / listitems  have been added to the intranet site and generate a report on daily basis ?

We have to implement this on sharepoint 2010 and also on sharepoint 2013 websites.
We are using C#.NET.
I am aware that we can find newly created listitems by creating  a listview and then sorting it by DATE as TODAY-2 where 2 is no. of days prior.
But, how can I implement same for all lists in the site? 
I am doing research on the web analytics in sharepoint 2010, but this doesnot seem to serve my purpose.

Have you come across similar requirement?

Comment: Could you add some more information to your question? Like what do you want to use? C# code? workflows? reporting-services? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you a small manual on how to create a separate ASPX-page in the _layouts folder. If something is unclear feel free to ask me in the comments of this answer.

I am assuming that you have already a solution set up for both versions SP2010 and SP2013.

1. Add a new ASPX-page (application-page) to the layouts mapped folder in your solution, lets name it "ViewNewContent.aspx".
2. In the codebehind in the page_load function, code something that loads all items that have `creation date > some defined date` and display them on the aspx page. Load the list using the GUID that you will pass as a Get-Parameter to the aspx-page (ViewNewContent.aspx?List={Some-GUID})
3. Now create a custom action that displays on all lists and redirects the user to the your page with the ListId added: `ViewNewContent.aspx?List={ListId}`

I hope this gives you a basic idea on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Ronon, thanks I have followed your method and it worked! I had 1 more questions:- Instead of this method, I could have created a custom web part in VS and deployed it on a web part page. Does this also make sense?

Comment: Yes, you could have also created a webpart for this